# Can I use the LastResort font in a web page?

Tags: font

I've read that Apple has a hidden system font, called "Last Resort", that's used as a last ditch effort to show a unicode character in some cases.

I'd like to use this font in a web page, to debug unicode issues. Is this possible?

I've tried using:

```
font-family: "LastResort"
```

in CSS, but it didnt seem to work. Any suggestions?

EDIT: Note I originally put the attribute "font-face", which I've changed to "font-family", and have been using in my local tests.

Comment: 1. Please provide a source for macOS having the font. 2. Just because macOS has it doesn't mean Safari can access it and therefore the developer can access it through CSS. 3. This seems like an [XY Problem](http://xyproblem.info). If you are having trouble with Unicode characters while developing for the web, I would suggest asking your about  original issue on stack overflow.

Comment: Ok it does exist. /System/Library/Fonts

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I suggest you use a different font which has the actual numbers of the characters and not just symbols like Last Resort.  [Here](https://scripts.sil.org/cms/scripts/page.php?site_id=nrsi&id=unicodebmpfallbackfont) is one, but it does not cover higher ranges of Unicode where many emoji are.  Another which seems to cover more characters is [GNU Unifont](http://unifoundry.com/unifont/index.html).

Comment: I've found another font called `Unifont` which seems good for this purpose as well. [More details here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54808618/26510)

Answer (score 2):

Use the following instead:

```
font-family: 'LastResort';
```

However, this seems like an [XY Problem](http://xyproblem.info/). If you are having trouble with Unicode characters while developing for the web, I would suggest asking about your original issue on [Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com).

---

**Note**: [`font-face`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/@font-face) is not a valid CSS property.  It is an [at-rule](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/At-rule). The correct property is [`font-family`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/CSS/font-family).

Comment: @TomGewecke lol. Please read my answer again *I would suggest asking your about original issue*. Not this issue, but whatever he is trying to debug. Which would be a code related problem, which is why I suggested SO. Also my answer actually answers the question so idk why its -1.

Comment: thanks for the feedback @JBis - it's a data issue - me wanting to see backspace, tab, and other non printable characters visually in a web page, when they've been input from user data. And I meant `font-family`, and just mistyped it above... thanks!

Comment: @BradParks the `font-family` does work on my system is it not working on yours?

Comment: I tried again, and it did.... I'm not sure what I was missing before... I must've mistyped something, but I actually can still see it there in my history exactly as you typed it. Maybe I forgot to "save" ? Thanks for the help!

Comment: @BradParks Glad I could help.